# 'Message' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to use this in my code:

```
if ctx.user.server_permissions.administator:
```

However, I am being presented with the error:

> 'Message' object has no attribute 'user'

I have also tried `ctx.author.server_permissions.administrator` but neither seems to work.

Comment: you can use a decorator for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```py
ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator
```

So,

```py
if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
    await ctx.send('You are an administrator!')
else:
    await ctx.send('Sorry, you are not an administrator.')
```

---

You can also use this:

```py
ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator
```

So,

```py
if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
    await ctx.send('You are an administrator!')
else:
    await ctx.send('Sorry, you are not an administrator.')
```

Comment: Hi, when using this in my code it gives me a similar error saying, Message' object has no attribute 'message'

Comment: @Pois, I've updated my answer. Try using it without `message` then. I've tested both and they work properly. Check if you have passed `ctx` as an argument. Also check if you are using the latest version of `discord.py`.